# Json 3D model only using 1 pixel of a texture

Tags: three.js

I'm having this weird issue, my 3D object is only taking 1 pixel (bottom left) of my texture, this is how i'm loading the object

```
  loaderFrame.load('./models/filterFrame/filterFrame.json',(geometry) =>
  {
  const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./models/filterFrame/textura_polar.jpeg'),
    transparent: true,
    morphTargets: true
  });

  mat.transparent = true;
 // mat.morphTargets = true;

  frameMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat);

  frameMesh.scale.multiplyScalar(frameOptions.frameScale);

  frameMesh.frustumCulled = false;
  frameMesh.transparent = true;
  frameMesh.renderOrder = 0;
}
```

);

Comment: Looks like UV coordinates are wrong or don't exist on the model.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your loaded object doesn't have proper [UV mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping). If UVs are nonexistent, or if they're all `0, 0`, then it's only going to sample from the bottom-left corner of your texture.

To fix this, open your model in a 3D editor and make sure the UVs are properly positioned across the texture plane. I don't know what your model looks like, but here's a basic example: [image]